# How to grant Refresh permissions to the materialized view to user in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, view, refresh

I am executing sql file on linux by running script.

I can see my queries are getting executed fine but I have following query to refresh view in my testData.sql file that is giving me the error

```
refresh MATERIALIZED VIEW view_test
```

Error

```
psql:/home/test/sql/testData.sql:111: ERROR:  must be owner of relation view_test
```

I have applied following permissions

```
grant select,update,delete,insert on view_test to "user123";
```

How to grant **refresh** permissions to the View in **POSTGRESQL**?

Comment: answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171932)

Comment: @JGH I have implemented the solution using the above given link but I was looking for if there is any other way to do the same.

Answer (score 8):

You should [create a new role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) to own the view, then [grant that role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-ROLES) to any users who need permission to refresh the view. This ensures that you can easily assign the permission when you need to create additional user credentials.

```sql
CREATE ROLE refresh_materialized_views;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON view_test TO refresh_materialized_views;
GRANT refresh_materialized_views TO user123;
GRANT refresh_materialized_views TO current_owner_of_view_test;
ALTER TABLE view_test OWNER TO refresh_materialized_views;
```

A tempting answer would be to alter the owner of the view to user123, but that's dangerous - you'd be breaking the current owner's access to their view.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a new role and set it as the new owner of the materialized view. Then add that role to any users you want able to refresh. This way an authenticated database user is not the owner, and you can add/remove users with permissions to it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Error `PostgreSQL` requires us must be an owner for refreshing `view_test`. You can use `alter table view_test owner to 'user123'` command for changing the owner of this materialized view to `user123`