# GRANT command return ERROR: EXPLAIN GRANT

Tags: sql, postgresql, navicat

In the application **Navicat for PostgreSQL** I am trying to apply a command to issue permissions to update a materialized view for a user.

```
GRANT REFRESH ON MATERIALIZED VIEW *materialized_view* TO *user*;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GRANT"
LINE 1: EXPLAIN GRANT REFRESH ON MATERIALIZED VIEW materialized_view...
                
, Time: 0.073000s
```

I'm new to database administration, can you tell me what could be wrong with my command? I would also be grateful, "if you throw at me" documentation

I tried to find at least some answers, but could not

Comment: You likely have _another_ SQL command located before the `GRANT` keyword which is not terminated with a semicolon. What happens if you use other Postgres tooling directly? (A quick-fix is to add a "`;`" right-before the `GRANT` keyword).

Comment: The thing is, there is nothing else. The only line that starts with GRANT command

Comment: I'm not familiar with Navicat, but is it altering your SQL? [Have you done a trace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dynamic-trace.html) to see exactly what's going on?

Comment: The same case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584212/how-to-grant-refresh-permissions-to-the-materialized-view-to-user-in-postgresql Greetings, Alejandro

Comment: You probably configured Navicat to generate an execution plan. I don't know Navicat, but that would be the symptoms.